# Using vectorized evaluation of Pymoo to solve a multi objective problem throwing Error: Number of values and population size do not match

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I have been looking for MOO solvers in Python and am interested in using Pymoo to solve a multi objective optimisation problem.

The variable in the problem is vector of weights X (for each element in vector V) which should be optimized such that the two objectives and two constraints defined below are satisfied.

My objectives are a) to minimise the overall cost by selecting weights in Vector V, when multiplied with cost Vector C, and similarly b) minimise overall quality factor which is stored in vector Q for each element.

When I run the below code, I get error:
*Exception: Population Set Attribute Error: Number of values and population size do not match!*

Apologies in advance I am neither an expert in NSGA II nor in Python and I couldn't locate guidance on how to select the population size for NSGA II or optimal value for n_gen, so please bear with me if I have made obvious errors here...any pointers here will be gratefully received.

```
import numpy as np
from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.model.problem import Problem
from pymoo.optimize import minimize
from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter


target=142
V=np.array([173.3, 5678.8,67898.98, 67898.0, 678987.0, 9876.87, 7659.9 ])
C=np.array([0.1,0.2,0.56,0.56,0.22,0.35,0.21])
L=np.array([1,1,0,0,0,0,1])
Q=np.array([2,3,3,4,2,2,4])



class MyProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(n_var=1,
                         n_obj=2,
                         n_constr=2,
                         xl=np.array([0]),
                         xu=np.array([1]))


    def _evaluate(self, X, out, *args, **kwargs):
        f1 = np.dot(C,np.multiply(X[:,0],V))
        f2 = np.dot(Q,np.multiply(X[:,0],V))

        g1 = np.dot(X[:,0],V)-target
        g2 =  0.2*target - np.dot(L,np.multiply(X[:,0],V))

        out["F"] = np.column_stack([f1,f2])
        out["G"] = np.column_stack([g1, g2])


problem = MyProblem()

algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=7)

res = minimize(problem,algorithm,('n_gen', 50), verbose=True)
```

CC: @julian
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4900707/julian

Comment: Hi, did you work out how to do it ? I have similar problem, I think!

Answer (score 0):

The evaluate method has the input `X` which is actually not a numpy array. I'm not really sure what it is but it has `n_var` elements. This is the mistake on the code, you consider 1 input of 7 elements while there should be 7 inputs.

Therefore, the resulting working code would be:

```py
import numpy as np
from pymoo.algorithms.moo.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.optimize import minimize
from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter
from pymoo.core.problem import Problem

target=142
V=np.array([173.3, 5678.8, 67898.98, 67898.0, 678987.0, 9876.87, 7659.9 ])
C=np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.56, 0.56, 0.22, 0.35, 0.21])
L=np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
Q=np.array([2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4])



class MyProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(n_var=7,
                         n_obj=2,
                         n_constr=0,
                         xl=np.array([0 for _ in range(7)]),
                         xu=np.array([1 for _ in range(7)]))


    def _evaluate(self, X, out, *args, **kwargs):
        f1 = np.dot(C,np.multiply(np.array(X),V))
        f2 = np.dot(Q,np.multiply(np.array(X),V))

        g1 = np.dot(np.array(X),V)-target
        g2 =  0.2*target - np.dot(L,np.multiply(np.array(X),V))

        out["F"] = np.column_stack([f1, f2])
        out["G"] = np.column_stack([g1, g2])


problem = MyProblem()

algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=7)

res = minimize(problem,algorithm,('n_gen', 50), verbose=True)
```

Note that i have changed:

1. `n_var`, `xl` and `xu` in Problems initialization
2. Usage of `X` in the `_evaluate` function
3. Some pymoo imports paths, due to versions i suppose

The results of the script are:

```
(Pdb) res.F
array([[ 119.17360983,  918.48554435],
       [ 114.1937054 ,  957.75142452],
       [ 111.48591563, 1076.51007568]])
(Pdb) res.X
array([[0.33654657, 0.77758381, 0.98287228, 0.60879627, 0.02302704,
        0.26922177, 0.54006553],
       [0.33654657, 0.77758381, 0.98287228, 0.60879627, 0.02268798,
        0.26921146, 0.55726625],
       [0.33654657, 0.77758381, 0.98287228, 0.5726368 , 0.02268798,
        0.26921146, 0.55716518]])
```